# Fitting table latex | 2 columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, two-column

[image]I am trying to fit a table in a essay of two columns. What I want is that this table fits in the two columns. Aditionally would be awesome if you can help me with the title of the table above it.

**Edit:**
This is my full code:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}
\usepackage{url}

\title{DANIEL\textunderscore LK\textunderscore B\textunderscore 2\textunderscore BIOFUELS}

\author{Daniel Itzamna Avila Ortega} 
\affiliation{Leiden University: s1868985 \\ TU Delft: 4628934}

\leftheader{Avila Ortega}
\shorttitle{Embedding FIS within MLP for biofuels in the Netherlands}

\begin{document}
\maketitle    

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table*}[h]
    \toprule
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\paperwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
    \hline 
    Function & Indicators \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
    \multirow {1: Entrepreneurial activities} & Number of actors by categories \\ 
    & Number of experiments \\
    & Number of activities \\
    \hline
    \multirow {2: Knowledge development} & Learning by searching: scientific papers \\
    & Learning by doing: biofuel production \\
    & Learning by using: number of biofuel flights \\
    \hline
    \multirow {3: Knowledge diffusion through networks} & Learning by interacting: National \& international knowledge exchange (joint research projects) \\
    & National \& international conferences, seminars, exhibitions \\
    & National \& international networks \\
    \hline
    \multirow {4: Guidance of search} & Policy targets (global, EU, NL) \\
    & Aviation biofuel program and initiative \\
    & Expectation and opinion by experts \\
    \hline
    \multirow {5: Market formation} & # of companies using aviation biofuel \\
    & # of routes constantly flying on aviation biofuel \\
    & Financial incentives available when selling aviation biofuel (subsidies) \\
    \hline
    \multirow {6: Resources mobilization} & Feedstock availability \\
    & Feedstock price \\
    & Access to financial resources \\
    & Attractivity of industry to graduate students \\
    \hline
    \multirow {7: Creation of legitimacy / counteract resistance to change} & Extent of biofuel promotion by government \\
    & # of active lobbying groups (for biofuels) in NL and EU \\
    & Public opinion on (aviation) biofuel \\
    & Position towards biofuel by public parties \\
    & Actions/reactions by incumbent oil refineries regarding aviation biofuel \\ [1ex]
    \hline
    \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
    \centering
    \caption {Indicators for FIS Analysis, \cite{Avila}}
    \label{table:FIS}
\end{table*}

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a  full compilable code, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: [This post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) may help you get started with making a minimal working example that could help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

Some general comments:

- You're completely mis-using `\multirow`. What are you *trying* to achieve? At any rate, it's not needed at all.
- If you wish to output `#` ("hashtag"), you need to input `\#`.
- Don't use `\toprule` outside tabular-like environments. It's not going to work.
- Instead of the `l` column type, use (at least) 1 column type that allows automatic line breaking. That way, you won't need `adjustbox` either. I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment and one `X` column, with the total width set to `\textwidth` (not `\paperwidth`!).
- Do give some thought to giving your table a more "open" look. I'd like to suggest you do so by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, and use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package for the few remaining lines. Your readers will thank you -- and they will reward you by actually looking at the table and taking in its contents...

[image]

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
 \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l
   >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X @{}}
\toprule 
Function & Indicators \\ 
\midrule
1: Entrepreneurial activities & Number of actors by categories \\ 
   & Number of experiments \\
   & Number of activities \\
\addlinespace
2: Knowledge development & Learning by searching: scientific papers \\
   & Learning by doing: biofuel production \\
   & Learning by using: number of biofuel flights \\
\addlinespace
3: Knowledge diffusion through networks & Learning by interacting: 
   National \& international knowledge exchange (joint research projects) \\
   & National \& international conferences, seminars, exhibitions \\
   & National \& international networks \\
\addlinespace
4: Guidance of search & Policy targets (global, EU, NL) \\
   & Aviation biofuel program and initiative \\
   & Expectation and opinion by experts \\
\addlinespace
5: Market formation & \# of companies using aviation biofuel \\
   & \# of routes constantly flying on aviation biofuel \\
   & Financial incentives available when selling aviation biofuel (subsidies) \\
\addlinespace
6: Resources mobilization & Feedstock availability \\
   & Feedstock price \\
   & Access to financial resources \\
   & Attractivity of industry to graduate students \\
\addlinespace
7: Creation of legitimacy\slash counteract resistance to change & Extent 
   of biofuel promotion by government \\
   & \# of active lobbying groups (for biofuels) in~NL and EU \\
   & Public opinion on (aviation) biofuel \\
   & Position towards biofuel by public parties \\
   & Actions\slash reactions by incumbent oil refineries regarding aviation biofuel \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption {Indicators for FIS Analysis, \cite{Avila}}
\label{table:FIS}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I basically copy your code, it is amazing! Thanks! However, I cannot still fix the title below... it is in a different row

Comment: @Daniel - I'm afraid I don't quite understand your concern. Please explain in more detail what you're trying to do and what's currently not working as expected. Do note that the `apa6` document class is set up to typeset captions flushleft, with a linebreak beween the label ("Table n", set with upright lettering) and the text of the caption itself (set with italic lettering).

Comment: Yeap the only problem that I have now is putting the title of the table in a single row, i.e. Table 1 Indicator for FIS. Instead my code is putting it in two rows with italics. I think this is what you mentioned about 'apa6'. If so, how can I possible fix this?

Comment: @Daniel - I assume you're using the `apa6` document class for a good reason. If so, I would certainly *not* modify any of the settings provided by the document class.